# how to develop testing tool for android?

Tags: mobile, android

I am very new to mobile testing. I do not have any knowledge of creating test tool for mobile application.

I want to create a test tool for Android 2.3 and above.

Can anyone describe how to make tools for mobile app testing.

Comment: Tool means? do you want to create your own mobile app testing tool? or you want to do automation for mobile app. testing?

Comment: yes I want to create my own mobile app testing tool for android ver 2.3 and above.

Comment: It require first to get very detail android knowledge , try some already created tool to get more idea.

Comment: I've edited the question to put the information about creating a tool into the body where it will be seen.

Answer (score 1):

I can describe a little about my experience of developing a tool used on android mobile, it may help you in finding a way:

So what I did, I created an app on android which used to browse the URL and play advertisements on it and perform some actions using javascript. For that, I first understood what is android life cycle and how to capture events in android. On events, I wrote my code using javascript to perform actions and validations.

This example may give you how you can proceed on building a tool provided you've already analyzed what you actually want to test.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In one sentence, ADB and UI Automator.

In a few more words:

ADB is your bridge into Android, you can actually run Linux shell commands ON the device, start activities, launch intents and even send key events. ADB is run from the command line, but this means you can easily integrate it into your favorite programming language.

UI Automator deals with the UI itself, you can analyze the structure of the application and send user responses to it.

many tools are based on those elements, so I suppose they are the best way to start with.